# Link path auto url to view field

Tags: 7, views, tokens, path-aliases

Does anyone know if its possible to attach a link to a specific node in a custom view and have that link be the path auto link?

I have a custom view that pulls in a title text field from an article. I want to have that text field be a link to go to that article and I only seem to be able to create a link to the node via a token the references the 'Content: nid' which outputs my link as www.site.com/node/66. I instead need the path to be my pathauto link.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a field **Content: Path** This would add another token which would be the aliased path of the node you can use that.

Please note that to use a token with in view the field should be above the field being used.

By the if you just want to Link the Title to its node then you can simply tick **"Link this field to the original piece of content"** This would link it to the article that the Title points to with the aliased url